# Socket.io client wont connect correctly

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

Im having problems figuring out how to implement websockets in my site. I seem to get errors on everything I try in the client.

This is how Ive got Apache set up:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxx.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/RoW
ErrorLog /var/www/html/RoW/logs/error.log

ProxyRequests on

ProxyPass / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33031/ retry=0
ProxyPassReverse / http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33031/ retry=0
</VirtualHost>
```

In my server backend:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log('User connected');
    
    UserController.init(socket);
    TplController.init(socket);
});
```

Ive tried multiple things in the client:

```
var Socket = io.connect();
console.log(Socket.connected);
```

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxx.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xxxxx' failed. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code : 400
false
```

Server console: `User connected`

Next

```
var Socket = io();
console.log(Socket.connected);
```

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxx.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xxxxx' failed. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code : 400
false
```

Server console: `User connected`

Next

```
var Socket = io('http://localhost');
console.log(Socket.connected);
```

```
false
```

Next

```
var Socket = io('http://xxxxx.com');
console.log(Socket.connected);
```

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxx.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xxxxx' failed. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code : 400
false
```

Server console: `User connected`

Next

```
var Socket = io('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:33031');
console.log(Socket.connected);
```

```
false
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to get a connection. I've searched for hours on google and SO, but nothing fits.

EDIT: After further testing, it appears all requests are in fact working via sockets when using `var Socket = io.connect();`. I'm just left with this unsightly error in the browser console:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://xxxxx.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=xxxxx' failed. Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code : 400
```

Comment: If you want to print the connection status on client side, try `Socket.on("connect",() => {
    console.log("Connected..",Socket.connected)
});` ..

Comment: Is it working correctly in local ??

Comment: In my code for the client side, you can see where I have `console.log(Socket.connected);`, however output is always false.

Comment: it always will be false, due to async nature of javascript. To log the status you'll need the above setup

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure to define server ip at backend that is**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
```

**Beneath this use your events like below**

**For connection**

[image]

**For events**

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly my setup.

Comment: are you getting console